# Import failing with ZFS pool that has both disks and files

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I recently ran out of space on my ZFS pool, and since I needed a quick solution for more space and didn't plan to use the pool for much longer, I just added a file as a new device (vdev?) to my pool of three disks to add some more space.

Unfortunately, after a recent reboot, I cannot import the pool. `zpool import` fails due to I/O errors, but `zpool import -F` complains of a missing device, and `zdb -e <pool name>` shows the file member of the pool to be missing. Specifically, it shows the pool has 4 children, and 3 have type 'disk' while the fourth shows:

`children[3]:
    type: 'missing'`

The file is in the same location with the same path that it has always had. Any ideas how I can fix the configuration and get this pool to import?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I figured it out 5 minutes after posting but hours after working on this with much frustration. I needed to specify the `-d` option in `zpool import` for both the path to the file AND to `/dev/disk/by-id`.